# How to use opencv in Django?

Tags: django, opencv

I'm a beginner in Django and I want to convert my image to grayscale before to upload it with opencv.
This is what I've tried to do but it doesn't work

`

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
import cv2

class Personne(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, help_text="Le nom est unique")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nom[:50]

def traitement(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
    cv2.imwrite(filename, img)


class Visage(models.Model):

    personne = models.ForeignKey(Personne)

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        return "Images/%s/%s" % (self.personne.nom, filename)

    traitement
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to=generate_filename)
    ajoute_le = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.path`
```

Comment: What is not working exactly? Any error messages or what?

Comment: I see error - bad indentation in 2nd line of class Personne. Maybe this is a problem (or fix yor code in a question). Also line "traitement" inside class Visage does nothing - what it is its purpose?

Comment: there's no errors, but when I upload my image, it doesn't convert to grayscale

Comment: img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
it converts the image to grayscale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override *save()* method of model *Visage* to do some actions with data after saving.
Change *your_project_name* appropriately.

```
from your_project_name.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Visage(models.Model):
    ... 

    def save(self):
        super(Visage, self).save()
        filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name)
        traitement(filename)
```

Comment: I didn't found MEDIA_ROOT in there. Sorry I'm beginner, what to put in there?
I've tried: MEDIA_ROOT='home/user/my_project_name/Images'
I didn't find the image

Comment: @Lilia refer to django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#media-root for using user uploaded files

Comment: It worked! Thank you 
I had to put in MEDIA_ROOT=' '